# Как понять, что Android-приложение потеряло фокус?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Во время работы приложения иногда бывает так, что открываются другие приложения, тем самым отнимая у моего приложения фокус.

Вопрос: как в таких ситуациях перезапускать приложение в службах, куда копать?

Comment: В этот момент вызывается [onPause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause())

Comment: Тогда уж `onStop()`, потому что `onPause()` сработает у активити, когда ее, к примеру, перекроет `Dialog`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно реализовать `Service`, в котором запустить какой-то таймер, который будет чекать `ActivityManager` и смотреть какая сейчас в стеке `topActivity`. И если это не ваша, то стартовать нужную.

**UPD.**

```
void check() {
    // получение Activity из верхнего таска
    ComponentName componentName = (mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0)).topActivity;
    String s = componentName.getPackageName();
    // сравнение текущего названия package с тем, который запущен
    if (!getPackageName().equals(s)) {
        // запуск своего приложения
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно поподробнее насчет Чекания?)

Comment: @TITAN, смотрите UPD. набросок метода